# How do I convert the rows of a csv file to dictionaries?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

My professor was not helpful when I asked him to clarify the question, and the TA did not reply to my email.

This is what the output should look like:

```
{'ID': '1', 'Name': '"Ying Pang"', 'Age': '18'}
{'ID': '2', 'Name': '"Matthew De La Rosa"', 'Age': '22'}
{'ID': '3', 'Name': '"Camille Jenkins"', 'Age': '20'}
```

I understand how to print out the csv rows as dictionaries by doing:

```
myFile = open('foo.csv', encoding='utf-8')
headers = next(myFile).rstrip().split(',') #headers
text = myFile.readline()
while text != "":
    print((dict(zip(headers, text.rstrip("\n").split(",")))))
    text = myFile.readline() #updates to next line
```

but I don't quite understand how to save this to a variable, or to a dictionary. I believe I need this as some sort of output, but not as an output to a file.

Comment: So you know how to print the rows as dictionaries, but you don't know how to convert them to dictionaries ... I am not following. If you print them as dictonaries, you must have already converted them to dictionaries.

Comment: instead of doing this print: print((dict(zip(headers, text.rstrip("\n").split(",")))))
you can simply write "myvar =  dict(zip(headers, text.rstrip("\n").split(",")))"
which will put that dict into myvar.

Comment: Can you use `csv.DictReader`?  That makes it almost a one-liner.

Comment: @MikeScotty I believe they have to be saved somewhere because we're going to have to convert that to a list of dictionaries in the next step. My professor was not helpful when I emailed him to clarify if printing them out was okay.

Comment: @Samwise nope. We're not allowed to use any modules/libraries except for json for another part of this assignment. I had completed the entire assignment earlier using csv and pandas, but now I'm revising my code to run without them.

Comment: @ShaunRamsey I'm a little confused how to store the entire thing in myvar. Right now in my while loop it keeps replacing the value, so I only end up with the last row stored in myvar.

Comment: You could merge the dictionary to other dictionaries. You can do that with
myvar = myvar | dict(...) on that line.

Comment: If you need them in a list, make a list before the loop: mylist = []
and then append the dicts to the list. mylist.append(myvar) after you create the dictionary.

Comment: What class or lesson is this? I’ve seen other people here on Stackoverflow that have been assigned to parse a CSV file without a real CSV parser. I genuinely want to know what value the professor thinks this has. Good luck 

Comment: A little bit of string parsing never hurt anyone @ZachYoung  hah

Comment: @ShaunRamsey, sometimes CSV can look like a simple string where splitting on a comma works, but it is an actual grammar that should be approached with a real parser: "The ABNF grammar [2] appears as follows...", from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2. And, having answered hundreds of CSV-related questions here, people trying to split on a comma do end up "harming" themselves. But, I was really asking, "what's the value?"

Comment: @ZachYoung I sent you a private message with the name of the class.

Comment: @ZachYoung You're right of course. Splitting on a comma in csv is dangerous at best. In introductory classes, where profs want their students to start playing with code and manipulating data, there is a huge tradeoff between using tools that automatically solve the problem (where the student learns nothing really) and moving into something bigger which is then completely overwhelming to the student. I remember my first lab was to write strcmp. Why write it when it is right there? All about making those neural connections so we can handle it for bigger problems. It isn't the route I go though.

Comment: @Zaku are you all settled now?

Comment: @ShaunRamsey, I was beginning to suspect the same motivation for the profs: “how do I say/enforce only module X is fair to use? Easier to say/enforce NO modules” and make sure the assignment’s CSV is simple enough. Thank you for sharing your perspective and experience!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could save each entry as a dictionary object within a list. You could do that using the code below.

```
file = open('test.csv', encoding='utf8')
headers = next(file).rstrip().split(',')

# This list will store all of the dictionary objects
entries = []

text = file.readline()
while text != '':
    #add the dictionary to the list
    entries.append(dict(zip(headers, text.rstrip('\n').split(',')))) 
    text = file.readline()


# all the entries are now stored in a list of dictionary objects called "entries"


# This function will search the list for the dictionary 
# object that corresponds to the type and value given
def get_entry(type_: str, value: str) -> dict:
    for item in entries:
        if item[type_] == value:
            return item


print("Entry for ID 1: ", get_entry('ID', '1'))
# outputs: "Entry for ID 1:  {'ID': '1', 'Name': 'Ying Pang', 'Age': '18'}"

# this would print all of the entries to standard output
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)

# this would output to file "output.out"
open('output.out', mode='w').writelines([str(entry) + '\n' for entry in entries])
```

Comment: The assignment prompt was not clear and my professor and TA did not respond when I emailed them about it. I was only told to this:

1. Read the attached CSV file one line at a time. 
2. Store the row(sic) as a dictionary.

The assignment prompt was not clear, and asking the professor for clarification did not work because he ignored what I had asked him. I showed him my code from printing out each line as a dictionary and he did not specify if that was what he wanted or not.

Answer (score 0):

To get each row of the CSV converted to a dict, and store each dict... you've written a great program so far.  One key point I think you're asking for is to just assign `dict(zip(...))` to a variable, then do something with that.

- I use `with open(...) as f` to open the file (and close it when the program steps out of the indented block); you also don't need `encoding='utf-8'` as that's the default for `open()`
- You were right to use `next(f)` to manually get the first line (the header); I'm using `for line in f:` to iterate the remaining lines
- I moved the line trimming and splitting to its own little function, `to_fields()`, to put that specific work in one place, and make the whole block easier to read
- I assign the result of your `dict(zip(...))` conversion to the variable `row`
- I save (append) `row` to the list `dict_rows`

```py
def to_fields(line):
    return line.rstrip().split(",")


dict_rows = []
with open("foo.csv") as f:
    line = next(f)
    header = to_fields(line)

    for line in f:
        fields = to_fields(line)
        row = dict(zip(header, fields))
        dict_rows.append(row)

print(dict_rows)

# [
#     {"ID": "1", "Name": '"Ying Pang"', "Age": "18"},
#     {"ID": "2", "Name": '"Matthew De La Rosa"', "Age": "22"},
#     {"ID": "3", "Name": '"Camille Jenkins"', "Age": "20"},
# ]
```

As for how to get each row out in a format your prof accepts...

```py
for row in dict_rows:
    print(row)

# {'ID': '1', 'Name': '"Ying Pang"', 'Age': '18'}
# {'ID': '2', 'Name': '"Matthew De La Rosa"', 'Age': '22'}
# {'ID': '3', 'Name': '"Camille Jenkins"', 'Age': '20'}
```

If it turns out you do need them written to a file, you'll need to somehow *string-ify* each row:

```py
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for row in dict_rows:
        f.write(str(row) + "\n")
```